# restore /dev after `rm`ing it

Tags: linux, gentoo, rm, udev, dev

during a gentoo install from the livedvd, there's one step to create a dev dir to be used later in the chroot of the target for the instalation

it's done like that

```
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/gentoo/dev
```

in the middle of the installation i decided to start over... so i just did

```
rm -fr /mnt/gentoo/*
```

thinking nothing of it ("will just unpack the stage3 tar ball again") i deleted most of the device files from my actual /dev since the ones in the chroot would be just binded to the real devices.

now, the easy solution is: reboot. i know that if I reboot they will be there again. But this is a livedvd with no persistence. So if I reboot i will lose ~1h of preparation with firmwares and whatnot,

for now i will reboot. But i'd like to learn how to restore a /dev if a case like this does happen again (and because now i need to know even if i will never use it again)

---

update:
just remembered about LFS. reading the linux from scratch docs, i think the simplest fix is to call

```
 /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

most of the files seems to be there now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*2014 update: Latest udev versions do not create device nodes at all, and rely on the kernel's devtmpfs to do so. The old answer will therefore stop working if your distribution has a very recent udev. With devtmpfs, the only automated method might be a reboot.*

---

/dev is managed by udev on most Linux distros, so

```
udevadm trigger
```

should help.

Restarting udev completely will also work, but it's not necessary, and the command highly depends on distro used.

NOTE: you have to create a few items manually before that command works. /dev/{zero,null}

Answer (score 2):

As seems to be no way to autorestore all files in `/dev` expect via rebooting, still:

```
# mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3 
# mknod -m 666 /dev/ptmx c 5 2
```

The above two commands restored working terminal (new tabs) and ability to start new GUI apps (inc. new terminal windows). Were learned from https://tldp.org/LDP/lfs/LFS-BOOK-6.1.1-HTML/chapter06/devices.html "Linux From Scratch - Version 6.1.1, 6.8. Populating /dev". Outdated as a whole afaik, but useful in parts.

Comment: Interestingly I've done `strace --follow-forks` of failed terminal launch and have not found neither `ptmx` not `/dev`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an expansion to Alex Martian's answer:

I also found out that udevadm won't restore all files. I fell down the rabbit hole with mknod, and wrote a script to do a more complete restore of /dev. First, create a backup of /dev:

```
 find /dev | xargs stat > devstat.txt
```

(of course it's best to create the backup on the same machine before the accident, but what I did was create a backup on a "similar enough" machine)

Then run the following script that will output commands that restores the contents of /dev:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0
l=0
d=0

while IFS= read -r line
do
        if [[ $line =~ File:\ (.*) ]]; then
                file=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi  
        if [[ $line =~ File:\ (.*)\ -\>\ (.*) ]]; then
                file=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
                link=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        fi  
        if [[ $line =~ Device\ type:\ ([0-9a-f]+),([0-9a-f]+) ]]; then
                major=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
                minor=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        fi  
        if [[ $line =~ character\ special\ file ]]; then
                c=1 
        fi  
        if [[ $line =~ symbolic\ link ]]; then
                l=1 
        fi  
        if [[ $line =~ directory ]]; then
                d=1 
        fi  
        if [[ $line =~ Access:\ \(([0-7]+)/c[rwx-]+\) ]]; then
                perm=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi  
        if [[ $line =~ Uid:\ \(\ *[0-9]+/\ *([a-z]+)\) ]]; then
                uid=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi  
        if [[ $line =~ Gid:\ \(\ *[0-9]+/\ *([a-z]+)\) ]]; then
                gid=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi  
        if [[ $line =~ Birth ]]; then
                if [[ $c -eq 1 ]]; then
                        echo mknod -m $perm $file c 0x$major 0x$minor
                        echo chown $uid:$gid $file
                fi  
                if [[ $l -eq 1 ]]; then
                        echo ln -s $link $file
                        echo chown $uid:$gid $file
                fi  
                if [[ $d -eq 1 ]]; then
                        echo mkdir -m $perm $file
                        echo chown $uid:$gid $file
                fi  
                c=0 
                l=0 
                d=0 
        fi  
done < devstat.txt
```

Review the commands created, then execute them on the machine in question.